# Do tag edits count as edits?

Tags: support, tags, edits, edit-badges

If I add or remove a tag from a question, does it count as an edit? If so, if I edit tags on enough posts, will I receive a badge as I would for other edits?

Suppose a question is tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php). Then I edit the post by adding another tag like [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Would such a change count as an edit, and if so, would it bring me any closer to a badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; changing tags counts as an edit. If you change nothing else, the default edit summary is “edited tags”. They do not, however, count towards edit-related badges.

Comment: `@icktoofay` so "edited tags" would be counted for `strunk & white` Badges.

Comment: @win No, tag-only edits do not count towards the edit badges. They do create a revision and show up as a revision in your activity.

Comment: @animuson are you sure it's still true? Now with the retag option gone, user with <2K rep create a suggested edit when changing tags and when approved, I think it's counted as "full" edit. No?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Still very true. In the end, a tag-only edit is exactly the same as they were before - there's just an extra step in the middle before they become actual edits. Besides, users with full editing privileges were still able to make tag-only edits without approval, and those didn't count either.